# What is the difference between $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$ baryons?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, isospin-symmetry

- The Lambda (uds) - 1115 MeV
- The Sigma (uds) - 1192 MeV

Other than the 77 MeV,  why are these 2 different particles?  Is it the spin of 1 quark?  If so, is it possible to determine which one?  If not spin, what could it be?

Comment: These course notes may help going deeper into the symmetries assigned to the hadrons https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys741/xji/chapter3.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/) summaries, the [$\Lambda $ bayrons](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/ParticleGroup.action?init=0&node=BXXX020) have [strong isospin](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/ParticleGroup.action?init=0&node=BXXX020) $I=0$, which means that there is only one charge state.
The [$\Sigma$ baryons](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/ParticleGroup.action?init=0&node=BXXX025), on the other hand, have $I=1$.

This means that all $\Lambda$ baryons are electrically neutral, while the $\Sigma$ (like the [$\pi$ meson](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/ParticleGroup.action?init=0&node=MXXX005), which also has $I=1$) may have charge zero or $\pm1$.

For what it's worth, the names attached to these particles categorize them by their quantum numbers; the links above list dozens of particles classified as $\Lambda$ or $\Sigma$.
The [lowest-mass $\Sigma^0$](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=S021), which I assume you're referring to as "the Sigma," isn't heavy enough for the isospin-conserving decay $\Sigma^0\to\Lambda\pi$, and therefore decays via the isospin-changing channel $\Sigma^0\to\Lambda\gamma$.
However, the more massive [$Σ(1385)$](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=B043) may undergo the isospin-conserving decay, and therefore has a much briefer lifetime.

The lightest $\Lambda$ baryons, however, can't decay without undergoing a strangeness-changing weak interaction, so the decay of the lightest $\Lambda^0$ is $10^{10}$ times slower than the decay of the lightest $\Sigma^0$.

Comment: one should also emphasize that the difference in mass is significant , which means they  are in different bound states of the same quarks, and that only a neutral was found at the mass of the Λ. This  necessitates different quantum numbers representing them and the isotopic spin assignment.

Answer (score -1):

"[Sigma baryons] are closely related to the Lambda baryons, which differ only in the wavefunction's behaviour upon flavour exchange."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_baryon